# Performance Attribution and FX positions

Tags: returns, performance-evaluation

I'm currently reading the book "Mastering Attribution" from Andrew Colin.

He first explains that you can separate the FX returns from the security return if the returns are **continous compounding**:

> Assuming **continuous compounding**, the base currency return $r_{BASE}$ of an asset is given by
> $$r_{BASE}=r_{LOCAL}+r_{FX}$$
> where $r_{LOCAL}$ is its local currency return, and $r_{FX}$ is the foreign exchange return due to changes in the exchange rate between the local and base currencies.

Then he explains that we can separate a portfolio in two subportfolios:

> For a clearer view of the effects of the manager’s investment decisions, one should
> treat this multi-currency portfolio as two subportfolios, one containing securities with returns measured in local currency and one containing FX positions. This allows the
> value added by local currency investment decisions to be separated from the
> value added by exchange rate movements.

From what I understand the fact that you can separate the effects is a consequence from the fact that the returns are compounded. If so, why he can add the returns multiplied by the weights if the returns are not arithmetical?

Comment: I believe you can always separate the effect of currency. If returns are continuous you have $r_{BASE}=r_{LOCAL}+r_{FX}$, if they are arithmetic you have $1+r_{BASE}=(1+r_{LOCAL})(1+r_{FX})$

Comment: @noob2 the problem is in that way you can't separe them additively in the arithmetic performance attribution

Comment: Yes, that is a big advantage of the continuous compounding method. But what is your question, then.